# Best way to level tile floor after drain tile installation?

Tags: basement, tile, laminate-floor

Had some flooding issues last spring and had drain tile installed in our basement. They cut away the tile to install the drain tile. Now we want to lay laminate over the tile but there's about a 2-3' gap between the wall and where the tile begins that is down to the original concrete. Question is, what is the best way to fill this gap to make the floor level? Suggestions we've been given are:
-self leveling concrete
-flooring underlayment
-cork
[image]

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you add some more pictures? It’s hard to tell what’s going on there.

Comment: what sort of tile was cut away?  ceramic? lino?

Comment: Tiles are ceramic